# CPU wait on GPU when renderer buffer size change

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

I'm working on an openGL ES based application for iOS. Things are looking good so far but, according to Instrument, there is a case when the CPU waits on the GPU. This warning is not consistent. When the warning appears, it seems to occur upon a change in the device orientation or a zooming. In the app, both those cases trigger a layoutSubviews call where (if there is a change in the view's frame), the dimensions of the frame buffer are updated via the code below:

```
[_context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer*)self.layer];
glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &_framebufferWidth);
glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &_framebufferHeight);
glViewport(0, 0, _framebufferWidth, _framebufferHeight);
```

Then in the drawing callback, the uniform matrix gets updated and then the following calls complete the drawing:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, sizeof(indices)/sizeof(indices[0]), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
[_context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
```

The glClear call seems to be the cause of the warning when there is a view size change. Honestly, this warning doesn't have any visual impact but I still would like to fix it but not sure how. With this question, I was hoping to get some sort of guidance on things to try. Any idea?

Comment: I believe this is normal behavior since the orientation and zooming is handled by OS handlers, which means you will block submitting requests to the GPU.

Comment: Thanks! Does it mean that if i have the drawing function running on a separate thread and the layoutSubviews on the main thread, this will not happen?

Comment: When you change orientation, and iOS runs the animation, it animates the last frame rendered. It depends on the code you wrote, if you are creating your own GLView, on the value of `contentMode` and many other things, but it's possible that iOS asks your view to redraw itself before running the animation, therefore the warning.
Running drawing functions on a different thread isn't a good idea... iOS manages the drawing; anyway you should sync them very well, and at least with OpenGL, I wasn't able to do that (the `glDrawXYZ` functions always raised EXC_BAD_ACCESS).